# Xamarin C# content page not loading image for Android JVM

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I have a problem attempting to load an image for the Android JVM in use on Visual Studio 2017 when debugging. Below is a sample of my code:

```
public class ImageDisplayPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ImageDisplayPage()
        {
            Content = new ScrollView
            {
                Content = new StackLayout()
                {
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                    Children =
                    {
                        new Image
                        {
                            IsVisible = true,
                            Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit,
                            Source = ImageSource.FromResource("Resources.a.png")
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

I have a folder in my project called "Resources" where the image is supposed to be loaded from, and have followed the path convention used in numerous posts on StackOverFlow and the guide listed here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images

I use Visual Studio 2017, coding in C# and when I attempt to debug this, the following message is what I get from the debug output:

```
Image data was invalid: Xamarin.Forms.StreamImageSource
```

The image in question is an 80kb PNG image.

Thank you in advance for any assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should place your image inside the Resources/drawable folder of your android project and only place the image name and the extension.

```
public class ImageDisplayPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ImageDisplayPage()
        {
            Content = new ScrollView
            {
                Content = new StackLayout()
                {
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                    Children =
                    {
                        new Image
                        {
                            IsVisible = true,
                            Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit,
                            Source = "a.png"
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi. I just tried your advice, and I got a different error message - "Could not find image file or image file was invalid: File: a.png". I copied and pasted the image to the folder you specified.

Comment: So after messing around with this a bit more, I converted the image back to a JPEG image after re-scaling the image to suit the size of the emulator interface a bit better. I will, however, mark this answer as correct, because the folder you said I should place the image into is the ONLY folder the image loads from correctly. I now don't understand why images of certain sizes are not loaded on the stacklayout AT ALL if they are too big, but that's a different issue. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @VCollins you should take a look at the [Xamarin Images Guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images/)